# using dragula with systemjs

Tags: angular, systemjs, dragula

I'm trying to use dragula in angular2 app with angular-cli.

```
<script src="vendor/dragula/dist/dragula.min.js"></script>

<script src="vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>

<script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

<script>
System.config({
  packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    dragula: 'vendor/dragula/dist/dragula.min.js'
  }
});
System.import('app.js').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

When I import dragula like this:

```
import * as dragula from 'dragula';
```

and try to use I get `dragula is not a function` error

Answer (score 0):

In fact the `dragula` variable isn't actually a function. Here is the content of this object:

```
Object {__useDefault: true}
  __useDefault:true
  default: dragula(initialContainers, options)
```

You should use the following to import and use the dragula function:

```
import * as dragula from 'dragula';

dragula.default(...);
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/J0POatroAhqfV9LDQQ5g?p=preview.

Comment: When I try to use like that dragula.default() I get error: 'Property 'default' does not exist on type 'Dragula'. I installed `typings install dragula --save --ambient`, maybe problem in it.

Comment: Is it a problem at compilation or at runtime?

Comment: On compile I use ng2-dragula components inside of my app